# why alignment of char array is 4 byte(gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9, cotrex-M4F)

Tags: arrays, c, gcc, alignment, arm-none-eabi-gcc

define `const char aa bb cc` variables, the alignment of memory map seems likes difference between `const char bb` and `const char bb[1]`

```
const char aa = 0;
const char bb = 1;
const char cc = 2;

.rodata.aa
                0x0005dbb0        0x1 ./source/main.o
                0x0005dbb0                aa
.rodata.bb
                0x0005dbb1        0x1 ./source/main.o
                0x0005dbb1                bb
.rodata.cc
                0x0005dbb2        0x1 ./source/main.o
                0x0005dbb2                cc
```

```
const char aa = 0;
const char bb[1] = {1};
const char cc = 2;

.rodata.aa
                0x0005dbb0        0x1 ./source/main.o
                0x0005dbb0                aa
*fill*          0x0005dbb1        0x3
.rodata.bb
                0x0005dbb4        0x1 ./source/main.o //why align to 4 byte here?
                0x0005dbb4                bb
.rodata.cc
                0x0005dbb5        0x1 ./source/main.o
                0x0005dbb5                cc
```

why, `const char bb[1]` align to 4 byte ?

how to make `const char bb[1]` align to 1 byte, like `const char bb`

Comment: What does `printf("%d\n", CHAR_BIT);` print on that platform?

Comment: Do you get the same result if you enable optimizations?

Comment: Please fix your formatting. /// Please use different names for the different variables. Asking for the difference `bb` and `bb` is needlessly confusing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for replying, my IDE the `CHAR_BIT` is `#define _EWL_CHAR_BIT 8`

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for replying, i have tried `-O2` or `-O0`, both optimizations `bb[1]` aligned to 4 byte

Comment: That doesn't answer Ted's question `_EWL_CHAR_BIT` is not `CHAR_BIT`. (No idea why @TedLyngmo think this matters, since the question is the same whether `CHAR_BIT` is 8, 32 or something in between.)

Comment: @ikegami I was thinking that a `CHAR_BIT` of 32 could explain it but I was just clutching at straws. Molly, you could `#include <limits.h>` and then do `printf("%d\n", CHAR_BIT);` to give the proper answer though.

Comment: Sorry for my English, and this is my first-time using Stack overflow. I just want to know the rule of the alignment of char array in my complier. thank you

Comment: @TedLyngmo , I typed `CHAR_BIT` and open declaration, find `#define CHAR_BIT _EWL_CHAR_BIT`, and open declaration of `_EWL_CHAR_BIT`, find `#define _EWL_CHAR_BIT 8`. because the embedded development board is at company, I cannot try `printf` now.

Comment: @molly The macro definitions you find like that may or may not be relevant. Compiling the program (`printf("%d\n", CHAR_BIT);`) for your target platform and then running it will give the proper answer.

Comment: hi @TedLyngmo, I checked the `CHAR_BIT` is 8.  using code `const char test = CHAR_BIT`, and check the map address of `test`, and the address value at srec file is 8.  @ikegami FYI

Comment: @molly Ok, it was a wild-goose chase on my part then,

Comment: hi, @TedLyngmo Is there any reason to explain the question.

Comment: molly: As I mentioned when @ikegami wondered about my queston too, I thought that `CHAR_BIT` might have been 32 on your platform and that that would explain the alignment. Don't think about it anymore. I'll leave my ill-educated questions here to prevent anyone else from going down that rabbit-hole.

Comment: Re "*and that that would explain the alignment*", No it wouldn't. The addresses are clearly in terms of `char`-sized units since &cc = &bb + 1

Comment: @TedLyngmo, i use my target platform and then running it, `printf("%d\n", CHAR_BIT)`  is 8.

Comment: Hi, @ikegami, using code `const char bb[1] __attribute__ ((aligned (1))) = {1}`  is helpful to align `bb[1]` at 1 byte. Looking forward to hearing from you.